# android change image width but don't keep aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, xml, resize, imageview

I need to change a image width

original image like the first line below:

[image: Figure]

but when I change the width it keeps the ratio resize the original image

I need to do something like the third image

can change the width and don't modify original image

How can I do this through Java or XML in android?

xml code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fill"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BGfill"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Comment: what is in the layout xml? specifically the view where you are setting the image

Comment: Set the scaleType.  There's several options, some of which preserve the ratio, some don't.  One of the fit types may be what you're looking for, but I'm not sure exactly what you want

Comment: added xml code,tried scaleType not working..

Comment: Try to set a `scaleType` value to `fitStart`